# 'git grep' and word boundaries on Mac OS X and BSD

Tags: regex, macos, git, grep, bsd

I run `git grep "\<blah\>"` regularly on my linux development server, but I just discovered that I am not able to use `\<` and `\>` on Mac (Mac OS X 10.6.8) (not able to use = it does not find anything). Is the regular expressions syntax different in Mac?

I tried using `git grep -E "\<blah\>"` but to no avail! :-(

Comment: It could be because you're not using the same shell on your mac as the one you use on linux. Maybe the one you use on `Mac OS` requires you escape your backslashes (e.g. double them).

Comment: I am able to do `git grep ">"` under Lion and get lots of matches.  Perhaps there is something wrong with your set-up...

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Doubling the backslashes does not help. Searching for `\>` just searches for closed angle bracket, instead of end of word boundary. I will try apple.stackexchange.com. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 10):

After struggling with this, too, I found [this very helpful post](http://mail-index.netbsd.org/tech-userlevel/2012/12/02/msg006954.html) on a BSD mailing list. So here's the (albeit rather ugly) solution:

```
git grep "[[:<:]]blah[[:>:]]"
```

The `-w` flag of git-grep also works but sometimes you want to only match the beginning or end of a word.

**Update:** This has changed in OS X 10.9 "Mavericks". Now you can use `\<`, `\>`, and `\b`. `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are no longer supported.

Comment: `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` still seem to work with `/usr/bin/grep` on macOS Sierra. Are you sure you aren't using `/usr/local/bin/grep` or some such arrangement?

Comment: Ah. I thought the difference was caused by the underlying (system) regex library. I guess Git might have used this previously on Mac, and now (since the version in Mavericks) uses its own (which is more "normal" in this regard).

Comment: How about relocating the correct answer from the comment section to the actual post?

Answer (score 8):

I guess it's caused by the BSD vs Linux grep library.

See if the `-w` (match pattern only at word boundary) option to git grep does it for you:

```
$ git grep -w blah
```

Answer (score 5):

You can compile git with `PCRE` support and use `git grep -P "\bblah\b"` for word boundaries.

Here's a guide on how to compile git using OSX Homebrew:
http://realultimateprogramming.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-enable-git-grep-p-on-os-x-using.html

Comment: this seems to be the default now on macos. at least, i never had to re-compile in order to use `-P`

Answer (score 0):

If you do use `-P`, make sure to use Git 2.40 (Q1 2023): "`grep -P`" learned to use Unicode Character Property to grok character classes when processing `\b` and `\w` etc.

See [commit acabd20](https://github.com/git/git/commit/acabd2048ee0ee53728100408970ab45a6dab65e) (08 Jan 2023) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 557d93a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/557d93a146b3f01e4e90c7c34fb9e9809ef95a81), 27 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`grep`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/acabd2048ee0ee53728100408970ab45a6dab65e): correctly identify utf-8 characters with `\{b,w}` in `-P`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> When UTF is enabled for a PCRE match, the corresponding flags are added to the `pcre2_compile()` call, but `PCRE2_UCP` wasn't included.
>
> This prevents extending the meaning of the character classes to include those new valid characters and therefore result in failed matches for expressions that rely on that extention, for ex:
>
> ```
> $ git grep -P '\bÆvar'
> ```
>
> Add `PCRE2_UCP` so that `\w` will include `Æ` and therefore `\b` could correctly match the beginning of that word.
>
> This has an impact on performance that has been estimated to be between 20% to 40% and that is shown through the added performance test.

That means those patterns will work, with any character:

```
'\bhow' 
'\bÆvar'
'\d+ \bÆvar'
'\bBelón\b'
'\w{12}\b'
```

---

With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), a recent-ish change to allow Unicode character classes to be used with "`grep -P`" triggered a JIT bug in older `pcre2` libraries.
The problematic change in Git built with these older libraries has been disabled to work around the bug.

See [commit 14b9a04](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14b9a044798ebb3858a1f1a1377309a3d6054ac8) (23 Mar 2023) by [Mathias Krause (`mathiaskrause`)](https://github.com/mathiaskrause).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d35cd54](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d35cd54a23f8114dd6924f705cd125c71b8c1746), 30 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`grep`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14b9a044798ebb3858a1f1a1377309a3d6054ac8): work around UTF-8 related JIT bug in PCRE2 <= 10.34
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Stephane Odul</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Mathias Krause</sup>

> [Stephane is reporting](https://lore.kernel.org/git/7E83DAA1-F9A9-4151-8D07-D80EA6D59EEA@clumio.com/) a regression introduced in Git v2.40.0 that leads to '[`git grep`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/14b9a044798ebb3858a1f1a1377309a3d6054ac8/Documentation/git-grep.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep))</sup> segfaulting in his CI pipeline.
> It turns out, he's using an older version of `libpcre2` that triggers a wild pointer dereference in the generated JIT code that was fixed in PCRE2 10.35.
>
> Instead of completely disabling the JIT compiler for the buggy version, just mask out the Unicode property handling as we used to do prior to [commit acabd20](https://github.com/git/git/commit/acabd2048ee0ee53728100408970ab45a6dab65e) (`grep`: correctly identify utf-8 characters with {b, 2023-01-08, Git v2.40.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/557d93a146b3f01e4e90c7c34fb9e9809ef95a81) listed in [batch #11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cc9858f1b470844dea5c5d3e936af183fdf2c68)) ("`grep`: correctly identify utf-8 characters with `\{b,w}` in `-P`").